# Regex: Alternative to .* expression to define word sequence

Tags: python, regex, syntax, regex-lookarounds

i am currently trying to match specific sentences based on the words they contain and their order. I am doing this mostly with the lookahead assertion based on this structure:

`[^>.\]]*(?="The desired Words)[^<.\]]*`

So i am for example looking for sentences that talk about Vacation in the Maledives. To match the sentence: i´ll book a vacation to the Maledives. I could look for sentences that contain the word vacation and afterwards maledives.

The expression `[^>.\]]*(?=([Vv]cation.*[Mm]aledives))[^<.\]]*` using `.*` causes problems because the word "Maledives" can also appear in later sentences ([Example Wrong](https://regexr.com/6oe45))

My solutionw as to use the expression `` ([,'`´() \\]*\w+){0,X}\s* `` instead of `.*`, to indicate that "Maledives" has to follow "vacation" within the same sentences and with a maximum of X words between them, changing to this structure:

`` [^>.\]]*(?=([Vv]cation([,'`´() \\]*\w+){0,X}\s*[Mm]aledives))[^<.\]]* `` ([Example Correct](https://regexr.com/6oei4))

Unfortunately this expression is quite computationally intensive and leads to catastrophic backtracking if the range {0,X} is set to high.

Do you have any other suggestions how to look for sentences containing specific words in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
(?:^|\.)\s*([^.]*[Vv]acation[^.]*[Mm]aledives[^.]*(?:\.|$))
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/97UvCH/1

There is no need for lookahead .It will slow things down.

Comment: Follow-up Question (Please delete if i should open a new thread): Is there an efficient way to match sentences where a word is NOT followed by a specific other word with this structure? So basically negate e.g Maledives in our example.

Comment: @Coloniac try these.... not done bench marking.....  https://regex101.com/r/YbW2x9/1              https://regex101.com/r/GIr456/1

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is prone to catastrophic backtracking as there are nested quantifiers in the `{0,3}` repeating part and there are also leading optional quantifiers at the start of the pattern.

Python `re` does not support possessive quantifiers or atomic groups, but you can mimic that using a capture group in a lookahead assertion, and then use the backreference to that group when the assertion is true for the first part to reduce the backtracking a bit.

But the second part with the quantifier `{0,200}` should not be atomic because you want to allow backtracking to fit a variable number of words before matching maledives.

So the higher the number for the quantifier will be, the more possible paths are there to explore.

```
(?<!\S)(?=([^<>.\]]*[Vv]acation\b))\1(?:[,'`´() \\]+\w+){0,200}\s*[Mm]aledives\b[^<.\]]*
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?=` Positive lookahead assertion, assert what is to the right is

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `[^<>.\]]*[Vv]acation\b` Match optional chars other than the listed and then match vacation followed by a word boundary
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `\1` Match a backreference to group 1 (that is matched in the lookahead)
- `` (?:[,'`´() \\]+\w+){0,200} `` Repeat 0-n times one or more chars from the character class and then 1+ word characters
- `\s*[Mm]aledives` Match optional whitespace chars and then maledives
- `[^<.\]]*` Optionally match any character other than the listed in the character class

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/onjh99/1).

---

Another option could be using the PyPi regex module with an atomic group `(?>` for the first part:

```
(?<!\S)(?>[^<>.\]]*[Vv]acation\b)(?:[,'`´() \\]+\w+){0,3}\s*[Mm]aledives[^<.\]]*
```

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##7ZaxTsMwEIZn/BRHFpK2iirYUGnFyNAJiSUOwm3cxsL1RfY1oUK8VZ@gLxbcUBiKhKgQ0CHybfd/v3zy2b5iRTmai7pWiwItgZVz@cRYIYikNXAFNghHg1N@G4WjYXI/GMY8TTvJXZmKqSCFhk985jLpnT1s1mEEnKddXnWj537vvN9/4a6TjBep0DJTpXTeoOEDxpz3DoMhjIUBBRpLCeXOMoYbcDkudQZzBPKRS6/becRwPaWl0HoFarPWGiaIjyA@6E8AGKxiGHCzXQE7CQ7joZX/i/z9tH6lRXLlwIcAko5gImdoZeOxEDTNoVKU@6RGApxBhTZzX7XVUW3zcKZF/gLZuwz7j1LbPy1yQP/8@Fdr8ONk3mr7VlVbYRCxwipDYTO7xDNlMk@EuxGmBy6KGKvrVw)